# Why is recycle bin called "bin"?

Tags: windows-os

I understand why the word "recycle" is used.
I want to know why it is called a "bin".
Does "bin" mean "Binary" ?
or does it mean Trash ???

Comment: Definition of bin (Entry 1 of 3)
1: a box, frame, crib, or enclosed place used for storage
2 chiefly British : a can for trash or garbage : DUSTBIN

Comment: "_I understand why the word "recycle" is used_"  Being somewhat contrary, I'd be more likely to question "_recycle_"... To me, recycling is about reusing something that's been discarded (or its component parts) in new products; it conjures up images of little elves breaking your old documents into words and letters, and putting them on shelves ready for use in your next document (I know, I should see someone!). To me, it would be better called a "_Recovery_ bin", as it allows you to recover – intact – accidentally discarded documents.

Comment: @TripeHound Good point. But think the "recycle" part came up not because of what happens to the actual files but because of the _space_. Once emptied, the space that the files in the **bin** was hogging can be _recycled_ and can be used by other files

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a User Experience question it is an english language / etymology one.

Comment: @TripeHound if you've got to recover a letter you mistakenly threw away, better to get it out of the paper-recycling bin than the one with the food scraps and used tissues!

Answer (score 3):

The definition of bin is

> a receptacle in which to deposit rubbish.

So, yeah. It means a place for your trash that can be recycled/retrieved.

Comment: In less politically correct times ( the 1980s ) I think it was called 'Trash' on a Mac

Comment: @PhillipW it's "rubbish bin" on my Linux system, but the underlying folder is called .Trash-1000

Answer (score -1):

It's called a bin in the UK. I guess the US just brought the word over.